# Solidity Contract cost calcuation

Tags: solidity, remix, price

How can I calculate the cost of running my contract and running each function?

I've noticed in Ethereum when a transaction is successful we have a transaction cost and a execution cost, what the difference?

If I calculate all the execution cost of my functions, will that be the total for my whole contract?

Comment: What do you mean by "running my contract"? What do you mean by "the total for my whole contract"? How are we supposed to answer this question when there is no code provided, and no description of what tools you are planning to use (for example, web3.js)???

Comment: By running the contract I mean deploying it either on a java script VM or using testrpc, regarding tools I've mentioned in my tags solidity and remix already. 

Regarding total for my whole contract I mean gas running cost.

Comment: "total for my whole contract" is still unclear. You can run each function an infinite number of times, what would be "the total of your contract" then?

Comment: In-other words, how can I know the exact amount of gas to put in for the contract to run without running out of gas.

Comment: If it's your contract, then just put the maximum (block gas-limit). You will not be charged more than what will be used. Similar question [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/73461/16043), by the way. In the answer to that question, the relevant part to your question is at the bottom of the answer:

Comment: In general, the gas parameter is there to protect you from spending too much.

If you are 100% confident that the code is not "malicious" (for example, if it's your code), then you can just use a high enough value which will ensure the execution of your transaction.

Only the actual gas required will be used, **even though** you've stated a higher amount.

Note, however, that the account which you use in order to execute the transaction must hold sufficient funds (i.e., `gas * gasPrice`) in order for it to be executed, **even** if not all the gas is required for the execution.